# android socket DataOutputStream.writeUTF

Tags: java, android, sockets

I write socket client:

```
clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.102", 15780);
outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
```

All works. But I wont to send to server **UTF**-8 format messages and do so:

```
outToServer.writeBytes("msg#");//server tag
outToServer.writeUTF("hello");
//outToServer.writeUTF(str); //or another string
outToServer.writeBytes("\n");
outToServer.flush();
```

Messages become such:

[image: secret byte]

Tell me please why? How correctly send UTF messages?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`writeUTF()` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> First, two bytes are written to the output stream as if by the writeShort method giving the number of bytes to follow. This value is the number of bytes actually written out, not the length of the string.

You can encode the string as utf-8 yourself and then send the resulting byte array to the server using [`write()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29):

```
byte[] buf = "hello".getBytes("UTF-8");
outToServer.write(buf, 0, buf.length);
```